# Why hibernate wont autoincrement my primary key?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jdbc

I have these classes that I am inserting on the database (postgresql with hibernate):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CITA", schema = "COLINASCO", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "CITA_ID")})
public class Cita implements Serializable{
    private long id;
    private Date fecha;
    private Time hora;
    private Paciente paciente;
    private Empleado empleado;
    private Set<Tratamiento> listaTratamientos;

    public Cita() {
        fecha = null;
        hora = null;
        paciente = null;
        empleado = null;
        listaTratamientos = null;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CITA_GENERATOR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "CITA_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "CITA_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "CITA_ID", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "FECHA", nullable = false)
    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }

    @Column(name = "HORA", nullable = false)
    public Time getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public void setHora(Time hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PACIENTE_ID")
    public Paciente getPaciente() {
        return paciente;
    }

    public void setPaciente(Paciente paciente) {
        this.paciente = paciente;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EMPLEADO_ID")
    public Empleado getEmpleado() {
        return empleado;
    }

    public void setEmpleado(Empleado empleado) {
        this.empleado = empleado;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "CITA_TRATAMIENTO", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "TRATAMIENTO_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CITA_ID")},
    uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"CITA_ID", "TRATAMIENTO_ID"}, name = "CITA_TRATAMIENTO_ID")},
    schema = "COLINASCO")
    public Set<Tratamiento> getListaTratamientos() {
        return listaTratamientos;
    }

    public void setListaTratamientos(Set<Tratamiento> listaTratamientos) {
        this.listaTratamientos = listaTratamientos;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "TRATAMIENTO", schema = "COLINASCO")
public class Tratamiento implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private CategoriaTratamiento categoria;
    private String nombre;
    private double precio;
    private Date fechaRegistrado;
    private Date fechaActualizado;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Tratamiento.
     */
    public Tratamiento() {
        categoria = null;
        nombre = "";
        precio = 0;
        fechaRegistrado = null;
        fechaActualizado = null;
    }

    /**
     * Gets id.
     *
     * @return the id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "TRATAMIENTO_GENERATOR")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "TRATAMIENTO_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "TRATAMIENTO_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "TRATAMIENTO_ID", nullable = false)
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * Sets id.
     *
     * @param id the id
     */
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * Gets categoria.
     *
     * @return the categoria
     */
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "CATEGORIA", nullable = false)
    public CategoriaTratamiento getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    /**
     * Sets categoria.
     *
     * @param categoria the categoria
     */
    public void setCategoria(CategoriaTratamiento categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    /**
     * Gets nombre.
     *
     * @return the nombre
     */
    @Column(name = "NOMBRE", nullable = false)
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Sets nombre.
     *
     * @param nombre the nombre
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /**
     * Gets precio.
     *
     * @return the precio
     */
    @Column(name = "PRECIO", nullable = false)
    public double getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    /**
     * Sets precio.
     *
     * @param precio the precio
     */
    public void setPrecio(double precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    /**
     * Gets fecha registrado.
     *
     * @return the fecha registrado
     */
    @Column(name = "FECHA_REGISTRADO", nullable = false)
    public Date getFechaRegistrado() {
        return fechaRegistrado;
    }

    /**
     * Sets fecha registrado.
     *
     * @param fechaRegistrado the fecha registrado
     */
    public void setFechaRegistrado(Date fechaRegistrado) {
        this.fechaRegistrado = fechaRegistrado;
    }

    /**
     * Gets fecha actualizado.
     *
     * @return the fecha actualizado
     */
    @Column(name = "FECHA_ACTUALIZADO", nullable = false)
    public Date getFechaActualizado() {
        return fechaActualizado;
    }

    /**
     * Sets fecha actualizado.
     *
     * @param fechaActualizado the fecha actualizado
     */
    public void setFechaActualizado(Date fechaActualizado) {
        this.fechaActualizado = fechaActualizado;
    }

    /**
     * Funcion que me retorna el nombre del tratamiento por defecto
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nombre;
    }
}
```

The thing is when I insert the first data, everything goes fine. The problem is when I insert the second data with for example same "Tratamiento" but the "Cita" itself it's already different, so on the cross-table where I am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoopImpl(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._enterNestedEventLoop(WinApplication.java:218)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.enterNestedEventLoop(Application.java:511)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.EventLoop.enter(EventLoop.java:107)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.enterNestedEventLoop(QuantumToolkit.java:583)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.showAndWait(Stage.java:474)
    at com.proyectosao.colinasco.controladora.PantallaPrincipalControladora.abrirTab(PantallaPrincipalControladora.java:415)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor5.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 118 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1413)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1393)
    at com.proyectosao.colinasco.controladora.RegistrarCitaControladora.registrar(RegistrarCitaControladora.java:429)
    at com.proyectosao.colinasco.controladora.RegistrarCitaControladora.btnClick(RegistrarCitaControladora.java:224)
    ... 128 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1323)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    ... 131 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uk_n0x746ttlbl6x41chhogj09gi"
  Detail: Key (cita_id)=(1) already exists.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2182)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1911)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:173)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:645)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:495)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:441)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 139 more
```

Hibernate won't update the id so I can't insert a second "Cita" with the same "Tratamiento".

What's going on here? Why is this happening?

This is how I save the object:

```
@FXML
    private void registrar(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            //El objecto de empleado ya esta seleccionado cuando se busca

            Cita cita = new Cita();
            cita.setHora(java.sql.Time.valueOf(localTimeTextFieldHoraCita.getLocalTime()));
            cita.setFecha(java.sql.Date.valueOf(datePickerFechaCita.getValue()));
            cita.setEmpleado(ec.fromString(comboBoxEmpleadoCita.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()));
            cita.setPaciente(paciente);
            cita.setListaTratamientos(new HashSet<>(tableViewTratamiento.getItems()));

            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(cita);
            session.flush();
            tx.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx == null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Notificacion.mostrarNotificacion("Registro.", "Cita con " + paciente.getNombre().toUpperCase() + " " + paciente.getApellido().toUpperCase() + " registrada!");

        Stage stage = (Stage) btnBuscarPaciente.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }
```

Comment: Post your code. You should use Long rather than long for your ID. And it should be null before inserting it.

Comment: @JBNizet, code updated. By the way I changed the long for Long in every class and make it null before insert it. Still the same exception with the primary key when the second "Cita" is added.

Comment: ``@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;``

Comment: @Donald Wu, I changed it, still. Same exception. Postgresql forces the unique column and somehow it wont update the id primary key. Whats going on in there?

Comment: I have tried so many things, still searching for more on how to overcome this issue but so far, same exception with the unique primary key. It wont auto generate when i insert the same object.

Comment: I tested your code on Postgres and Oracle database, It works just fine. There is not problem in this code. Check your database maybe there is something wrong.